# Using NSJSONSerialization with InputStream

Tags: ios, json, swift

Could someone please explain the point of using an `NSInputStream` in `NSJSONSerialization`'s class func  `jsonObject`? I'm trying to download JSON data from a server and display it in real time. My current solution is just to perform an HTTP request with a download task (because I want background downloading).Will I get any additional speed by using the stream over a download task?  [Of course, to get the JSON, I have to make queries to an API, so I suspect that it will be impossible to use the socket approach currently - but should I look at developing my server to support this solution?]